# Installation of zabbix-server using docker-compose and connect with host mysql and apache server

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, devops, zabbix

I am new in docker technology.
I want to install zabbix server using docker-compose.yml with only one container and connect it with host machine database(mysql) and also host machine apache2/nginx for zabbix frontend.
Is it possible? Please help.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the official [Zabbix blog](https://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-docker-containers) tutorial:

Clone the zabbix-docker repository:

```
git clone https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker.git
cd zabbix-docker
```

Inside the `zabbix-docker` directory:

```
agent                                       docker-compose_v3_centos_mysql_latest.yaml  docker-compose_v3_ol_pgsql_local.yaml       kubernetes.yaml  snmptraps
agent2                                      docker-compose_v3_centos_mysql_local.yaml   docker-compose_v3_ubuntu_mysql_latest.yaml  LICENSE          web-apache-mysql
build.sh                                    docker-compose_v3_centos_pgsql_latest.yaml  docker-compose_v3_ubuntu_mysql_local.yaml   proxy-mysql      web-apache-pgsql
docker-compose_v3_alpine_mysql_latest.yaml  docker-compose_v3_centos_pgsql_local.yaml   docker-compose_v3_ubuntu_pgsql_latest.yaml  proxy-sqlite3    web-nginx-mysql
docker-compose_v3_alpine_mysql_local.yaml   docker-compose_v3_ol_mysql_latest.yaml      docker-compose_v3_ubuntu_pgsql_local.yaml   README.md        web-nginx-pgsql
docker-compose_v3_alpine_pgsql_latest.yaml  docker-compose_v3_ol_mysql_local.yaml       generate-stackbrew-library.sh               server-mysql     web-service
docker-compose_v3_alpine_pgsql_local.yaml   docker-compose_v3_ol_pgsql_latest.yaml      java-gateway                                server-pgsql     zabbix-appliance
```

Files ‘docker-compose-v2’ on the left are for an older Docker Compose version. Normally, if you have a fresh installation, you will not need them.

We will be using Docker Compose v3. What is the difference between those files with docker-compose-v3 in their name?

- First of all, there is a choice of operating systems: Alpine, CentOS or Ubuntu — three choices of distribution on which to run the container.

```
_alpine_
_centos_
_ubuntu_
```

- Then, there is a choice of databases which could be MySQL or Postgres. For each distribution you have a choice of database engines.

```
_mysql_
_pgsql_
```

- Last of all, there are two types — local and latest. The difference between those two is pretty simple.

```
_latest.yaml
_local.yaml
```

- **Local** means that we will be building an image locally from our local Docker files.
- **Latest** means that we will be pulling it from the repository.

Checkout the version of Zabbix you want:

```
git checkout 5.0
```

Run one of the `docker-compose` files <sup>1</sup>:

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose_v3_alpine_mysql_latest.yaml up -d
```

<sub><sup>1</sup> Checkout the available ports, otherwise the services may fail to start.</sub>

Read [their turorial](https://blog.zabbix.com/zabbix-docker-containers) for more information.

Answer (score 1):

That's the Docker Compose file I use. The difference here is that I use web frontend container instead of using host's Apache. On host Nginx I do proxy to the frontend.

I know using of the host network in containers isn't the best idea. But I had problems with backend and frontend connecting to my host's MySQL so this is a temporary workaround. Might be enough though for you.

Additionally I have following files in my compose directory:

.env_db_mysql  - downloaded from https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker

.env_srv  - downloaded from https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker

.env_web  - downloaded from https://github.com/zabbix/zabbix-docker

.MYSQL_PASSWORD  - contains a password to the DB

.MYSQL_USER - contains a user name to the DB

```
    version: '3.5'
    services:
        zabbix-server:
            image: zabbix/zabbix-server-mysql:alpine-5.2-latest
            ports:
                - "10051:10051"
            volumes:
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - ./zbx_env/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts:/usr/lib/zabbix/alertscripts:ro
            - ./zbx_env/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts:/usr/lib/zabbix/externalscripts:ro
            - ./zbx_env/var/lib/zabbix/export:/var/lib/zabbix/export:rw
            - ./zbx_env/var/lib/zabbix/modules:/var/lib/zabbix/modules:ro
            - ./zbx_env/var/lib/zabbix/enc:/var/lib/zabbix/enc:ro
            - ./zbx_env/var/lib/zabbix/ssh_keys:/var/lib/zabbix/ssh_keys:ro
            - ./zbx_env/var/lib/zabbix/mibs:/var/lib/zabbix/mibs:ro
            ulimits:
                nproc: 65535
                nofile:
                soft: 20000
                hard: 40000
            env_file:
            - .env_db_mysql
            - .env_srv
            secrets:
            - MYSQL_USER
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD
            network_mode: "host"
            stop_grace_period: 30s
            sysctls:
            - net.ipv4.ip_local_port_range=1024 65000
            - net.ipv4.conf.all.accept_redirects=0
            - net.ipv4.conf.all.secure_redirects=0
            - net.ipv4.conf.all.send_redirects=0
            labels:
                com.zabbix.description: "Zabbix server with MySQL database support"    
                com.zabbix.company: "Zabbix LLC"
                com.zabbix.component: "zabbix-server"
                com.zabbix.dbtype: "mysql"
                com.zabbix.os: "alpine"
    
        zabbix-web-nginx-mysql:
            image: zabbix/zabbix-web-nginx-mysql:alpine-5.2-latest
            ports:
            - "8081:8080"
            - "8443:8443"
            volumes:
            - /etc/localtime:/etc/localtime:ro
            - /etc/timezone:/etc/timezone:ro
            - ./zbx_env/etc/ssl/nginx:/etc/ssl/nginx:ro
            - ./zbx_env/usr/share/zabbix/modules/:/usr/share/zabbix/modules/:ro
            env_file:
            - .env_db_mysql
            - .env_web
            secrets:
            - MYSQL_USER
            - MYSQL_PASSWORD
            healthcheck:
                test: ["CMD", "curl", "-f", "http://localhost:8080/"]
                interval: 10s
                timeout: 5s
                retries: 3
            start_period: 30s
            network_mode: "host"
            stop_grace_period: 10s
            sysctls:
            - net.core.somaxconn=65535
            labels:
                com.zabbix.description: "Zabbix frontend on Nginx web-server with MySQL database support"
                com.zabbix.company: "Zabbix LLC"
                com.zabbix.component: "zabbix-frontend"
                com.zabbix.webserver: "nginx"
                com.zabbix.dbtype: "mysql"
                com.zabbix.os: "alpine"
    
    secrets:
        MYSQL_USER:
            file: ./.MYSQL_USER
        MYSQL_PASSWORD:
            file: ./.MYSQL_PASSWORD
```